# Invaluable VS valuable (help)

Tags: adjectives, grammaticality-in-context

What is a better way to thank someone: to use "invaluable" or "valuable".

"I cordially thank you for your invaluable help"

vs

"I cordially thank you for your valuable help"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Valuable** - of a particular (high) value.

**Invaluable** - of a value that is impossible to estimate.

Which one to use in any particular situation is really up to you.  Both are acceptable forms, as far as expressing gratitude goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can say either valuable help  or invaluable help.

Valuable means very important or useful, and invaluable means extremely important or useful (too important or useful to be estimated).

Both the words are adjectives; invaluable is stronger than valuable.